# KVM guest machine graphics problem

Tags: virtual-machine, graphics, kvm

I'm new to KVM. I use the following way to create and start a guest KVM machine.

```
qemu-img create -f raw centos.img 100G
/usr/libexec/qemu-kvm -hda ./centos.img -cdrom /usr/local/CentOS_5.6_Final.iso -m 1024 -smp 1 -boot d
/usr/libexec/qemu-kvm -hda ./centos.img -m 1024 -smp 1 -boot c
```

When the login page appears, everything seems right.

[image]

When I log into the system, it show me like this. Note the following image shows what I saw when I just log into the system, without move my mouse or press a key.
[image]

Take a closer look.
[image]

When I click the left mouse button, it shows me this menu.
[image]

Anyone can help me with my problem? How to fix the graphics in the guest machine?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you've installed X, but haven't installed any desktop environments (Gnome, KDE, XFCE, LXDE, etc), so you're getting the minimal bundled window manager.

Comment: Yep, it's twm: http://xwinman.org/vtwm.php